# From web forms to Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webforms, razor

I've got an .net 2.0 web forms site that has just been upgraded to .net 4. Now I'd like to use the Razor syntax and some mvc helpers. Could anyone give a step by step procedure to start using it?

(Yes, I know mixing different view engines is not straight forward, but I'm not asking for that. Just to be able to create a new _layout, and a new ContentPage.cshtml and start using some of the mvc helpers and get that to work in parallell with the old pages - I'll duplicate the masterpage functionality, so that new pages will be written using razor, and old pages bugfixed in webform with the old masterpage)

I just need to know the following:

- What assemblies do I need to include
- What changes to web.config do I need
- Any other changes?

Thanks for any help

Larsi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scott hanselman has a great post about this:

[Integrating ASP.NET MVC 3 into existing upgraded ASP.NET 4 Web Forms applications](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `System.Web.Mvc` version 3.0.

In your web.config, you need to make sure that the `UrlRoutingModule` is registered as an HttpModule.  Your `IHttpHandler` is created by the `IRouteHandler` implementation, which is an `MvcRouteHandler` in ASP.NET Mvc.

You also will need to register your routes in your `Global.asax` to setup routing.  The default Route registration (for an MVC2 project) looks like this:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

I'm not sure if they have made any changes to that in Mvc 3 or not, but you can find out by creating a new Mvc Web Application project in Visual Studio and opening up the `Global.asax`

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the [upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 2 Project to ASP.NET MVC 3](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#upgrading) guide. If you have a classic WebForms application (not MVC) then there is no migration => there is a rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

This converter tool will get you a head start:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d2bfd1ca-9808-417c-b963-eb1ea4896790

Answer (score 0):

Telerik wrote a command-line converter from aspx/ascx to cshtml for asp.net mvc. You can find that at: https://github.com/telerik/razor-converter

There is also a nice plugin for Visual Studio that uses the Telerik code at: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d2bfd1ca-9808-417c-b963-eb1ea4896790